How do I rotate one direction vector by another vector's direction away from positive z?
Let's say I have two normalized (-1 to 1) direction vectors A and B:
// positive y is "up"
A = (1.0, 0.0, 1.0) // 45° away from positive z
B = (0.0, 0.0, -1.0) // 180° away from positive z
????
result = (-1.0, 0.0, -1.0)

How do I rotate vector A by vector B's rotation away from positive z? What do I put in place of ????
Note: the y-coordinate is not always 0, I just made it 0 here to simplify the example
Note: Both vectors A and B are arbitrary and can be any combination of x, y, and z values ranging from -1 to 1. For example, A could be (0.65, 0.92, 1.0) and B could be (1.0, 0.8, 0.34). All axis of rotation of B away from positive z should be considered when rotating A, and not just the rotation around y.
Note: I also have access to vector B's quaternion, if it helps to simplify the math. It would be nice to see how to do it with and without the quaternion anyway.
Here is an image to elaborate:

Context: I am writing a shader in the 3D web rendering framework three.js in which I need to rotate a number of arbitrary direction vectors in the shader by the current viewport camera’s rotation away from the positive z-axis.
For example, if the camera is looking directly down the positive z-axis, the camera’s view direction vector would be (0,0,1). If the camera were looking directly up, the camera’s view direction vector would be (0,1,0).
In the shader there are numerous vectors that need to have the viewport camera’s direction applied to them, as described in the screenshot above.
The camera object is represented as an “Object3D” in three.js, and its view direction vector can be obtained by calling the method camera.getWorldDirection(). In the three.js documentation, the getWorldDirection() method is described by the following:

Returns a vector representing the direction of object's positive z-axis in world space. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldDirection

However, there is another method that returns a quaternion, and that method is called getWorldQuaternion(). This method is described by the following:

Returns a quaternion representing the rotation of the object in world space. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getWorldQuaternion

I’m not sure if this quaternion is there one being described in the answers so far, but hopefully the linked documentation can help.
Ideally, if you guys can help me out, I’d like to see the pseudo code needed to accomplish this using both getWorldDirection() (which returns a vector) and getWorldQuaternion() (which returns a quaternion).
When I say “pseudo code” I mean the individual math operations as they would appear in code, like the following for example:
var A = vec3(1,0,1)
var B = vec3(0,0,1)
// the following code is made up!!!
var result = dot(cross(A,B),cos(A.x))

So it would be awesome if the answer could include some code-like terms like cross(A,B) or dot(A,B). I’m a little rusty on standard vector and matrix notation and operators in math. Thanks!

The direction of a single vector is not enough to describe a rotation in 3D space. What if you had the same $B$, but $A$ was $(1,1,1)$? Would the result be $(-1,-1,-1)$, $(-1,1,-1)$, or something else? what if $B$ was $(0,1,0)$? Would $A=(1,0,1)$ get rotated to $(1,1,0)$, $(1,0,-1)$, or something else?

If $B$ is produced by applying some quaternion $q$ to a vector on the positive $z$ axis and the intention is to apply the same rotation quaternion to $A$, you need to have an adequate description of the rotation so that it can be identified uniquely. A quaternion is one such description. An axis and angle is another, A $3\times3$ matrix is another. The result of the rotation on a single vector is not, because if vector $P$ and vector $Q$ have the same magnitude, there are infinitely many rotations that take $P$ to $Q$. (And of course if the magnitudes are not equal there are no rotations.)

But you knew a lot of this, didn't you? "All axis of rotation of B away from positive z should be considered ... ." Indeed, we must consider all possible axes of rotation that could have produced $B$, and therefore we can only say with certainty that if you rotate $A$ by the same rotation you applied to the preimage of $B$, you'll arrive at a vector that makes the same angle with $B$ that $A$ makes with the $z$ axis. Why do you think we can deduce the unique answer to a question that has no unique answer?

The problem with getWorldDirection() is that it only tells you which direction is "forward" for the camera. (Or perhaps it's giving you the "backward" direction. I'm not familiar enough with this system to say which.)
getWorldDirection() doesn't tell you which direction is "up" for the camera or which direction is "right".

Obviously it matters how you get the viewport camera to the orientation you are viewing from. If the "unrotated" position of the camera means that you are looking down from the positive $z$ axis with the positive $x$ axis pointing to the right of the viewport, then $A = (1,0,1)$ also is pointing to the right. If you rotate the camera $180$ degrees around the $y$ axis, its getWorldDirection() vector reverses direction and you now "see" the vector $A$ pointing to the left of the viewport. [continued...]

[...continued] But if you rotate $180$ degrees around the $x$ axis, again the camera's getWorldDirection() vector reverses direction, but this time you "see" the vector $A$ pointing to the right. I can't imagine that your shader is going to work equally well when you give it a vector coming from the right as when you give it a vector coming from the left for the same scene viewed from the same orientation.

Since you are in a programming environment where it is easy to use quaternions to uniquely represent a rotation, you should use quaternions, full stop. I would just take care to use them correctly. If the camera got rotated by rotation $R$ to get to its new viewing orientation, you need to rotate $A$ by $R^{-1}$ (the "undo" rotation) in order to get the correct vector relative to the camera.

So what I'm understanding is you just want to move something else in the same way the camera has been moved? That's exactly what the camera's getWorldQuaternion() is for, is it not? You just need to apply this quaternion to your vectors/other quaternions.

Step 1: Calculate ''vector $B$'s rotation'':
\begin{align}
\cos\theta=B\cdot e_z
\end{align}
Step 2: Apply the rotation transformation by $\theta$ to vector $A$, both represented under standard basis $\{e_z,e_y\}$:
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\
-\sin\theta&\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
a_z\\a_y
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
If you want the full expression in $\mathbb{R}^3$ when $B$ is arbitrary, it amounts to calculating the Euler angles and apply succssive Euler transformations to $A$.

In my case both vectors A and B are arbitrary and can be any combination of x, y, and z values ranging from -1 to  1. For example, A could be (0.65, 0.92, 1.0) and B could be (1.0, 0.8, 0.34). All axis of rotation of B away from positive z should be considered when rotating A, and not just the rotation around y. With this information, is there any way you could share the individual math operations on the vectors? I used to be able to read the notation in your answer but I’m a little rusty.

Represent vectors as imaginary quaternions, with $i,j,k$ corresponding to the $x,y,z$ axes.
If $B = -k$ then $A \mapsto -A$. Now suppose $B\ne -k$.
The quaternion $q_0=w+v$ ($w$ real, $v$ imaginaro) taking a vector $b$ to a vector $a$ (with the angle between them as the angle of rotation) is $\sqrt{ab}$:
$$
  w^2 + 2wv + v^2 = ab
  \implies\begin{cases}
    w^2 + v^2 = -a\cdot b,\\ 
    2wv = a\times b,
  \end{cases}.
$$
As long as $w\ne0$ (equivalently $a\ne-\xi b$ for positive scalar $\xi$) we can uniquely solve for $w, v$ to get the (unnormalized) quaternion
$$
  q_0 = |a||b| + ab = |a||b| - a\cdot b + a\times b.
$$
When $a=B$ and $b=k$ we of course get
$$
  q_0 = 1 - B_z + B\times k.
$$
The angular information of $q_0$ is stored in the ratio of $w$ to $|v|$, so all we have to do is keep this ratio constant and replace the direction of $v$ with that of $A\times k$ to get the (unnormalized) quaternion $q$ you desire:
$$
  q = |A\times k|(1-B_z) + |B\times k|A\times k
$$
No trigonometry required!

I just noticed you said you have "vector $B$'s quaternion". If what you mean is that you have the quaternion taking $z$ to $B$ about the axis orthogonal to them, then this is exactly $q_0 = w + v$ above so you don't need to calculate that and can go directly to
$$
  q = |A\times k|w + |v|A\times k.
$$

This is awesome, thanks for the detailed answer. I added some context and info on the quaternion I mentioned to my original post (look at the end of the question); can you take a look and see if it makes sense?
